# Cannot log in to private beta

Tags: bug, login, private-beta

I was invited to the private beta for the new Puzzling.SE site. I clicked the link in the email and created my account on one computer. But when I go to the site on another computer, there is no way to log in without going back to my email and clicking the link again.

Why can't I just log in to the site since I'm already there?

Comment: I didn't think private beta's had their sign up process locked?

Comment: @ShadowWizard is there a point to marking this as a duplicate of an old, unanswered and dead question...?

Comment: @TravisJ not quite sure what you mean... nothing is "locked" exactly, I've already registered and been active on the site.

Comment: Yes, duplicate is duplicate.

Comment: OK well thanks for preventing this bug ever getting fixed.

Comment: Also notice how the duplicate message reads "This question has been asked before and **already has an answer.**" The other question doesn't have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way.

Go to the [proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45128/puzzling), and click on "Visit the site now". This will take you to the site and allow you to log in normally.